# Como gerar os dados para inferir sobre a população a partir da amostra? (Censo demográfico)

Tags: dataframe

Gerei o DataFrame com as variáveis de interesse, variável de controle e o peso amostral.
Agora preciso expandir os dados amostrais para poder começar a retirar informações corretas da base, tais como: população rural total, total de ocupados em atividades agropecuárias, etc.

````
catalog <- lodown::get_catalog(
  data_name = "censo",
  output_dir = "data" 
) %>%
  dplyr::filter(
    year == 2010, # Censo de 2010
    stringr::str_detect(state, "pe") # microdados de PE
  ) %>%
  lodown::lodown(data_name = "censo")
sas_input <- SAScii::parse.SAScii(catalog$pes_sas) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(varname = stringr::str_to_lower(varname))
fs::dir_tree(path = "data")
dplyr::as_tibble(sas_input)
vars_censo <- c("v0001", "v0002", "v1006", "v6461", "v6471", "v6527",
                "v6900", "v6910", "v0010", "v0011", "v0300")
raw_censo <- readr::read_fwf( 
  file = catalog$pes_file,   
  col_positions = readr::fwf_widths(    
    widths      = abs(sas_input$width),
    col_names   = sas_input$varname
  ),
  col_types = paste0(   # especificação de tipos de cada colunas (character/double/etc.)
    ifelse(
      !(sas_input$varname %in% vars_censo),
      "_",
      ifelse(sas_input$char, "c", "d")
    ),
    collapse = ""
  )
)
raw_censo2 <- na.omit(raw_censo)```
````